# Laravel 4 - CSS does not get loaded

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-4

I have imported a html page into my laravel 4 project. I linked all the js and css files together. However, when loading the page the page just outputs plain html.

This is my internal folder structure:
[image]

In my `main.blade.php` site I link to my css like that:

```
 <!-- CSS Files
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/mainPage/bootstrap.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/mainPage/jpreloader.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/mainPage/animate.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/mainPage/flexslider.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/mainPage/plugin.css')}}" type="text/css">
```

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others already pointed out, your missing the 'assets' at the beginning of your path. That's because it requires the full path *relative to the public folder*.
Besides that, I suggest you use the tools Laravel provides to generate the full link tag of your css includes. It makes your code a lot more cleaner.

```
{{ HTML::style('assets/css/mainPage/bootstrap.css') }}
```

And there's `HTML::script('path')` as well for javascript files

Answer (score 1):

give the full path of the directory under public folder:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/mainPage/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
 <!-- CSS Files
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/mainPage/bootstrap.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/mainPage/jpreloader.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/mainPage/animate.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/mainPage/flexslider.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/mainPage/plugin.css')}}" type="text/css">
```